# Prove a space is a solution for homogeneous system

Tags: linear-algebra

**All the question is above $Z_7$.**

I have a space:

$$
U = \{(1,-1,1,2),(3,0,2,1)\} \subseteq (Z_7)^4
$$

I need to prove that $U$ is the solution space for:

$$
*\left\{\begin{matrix}
2x-y-3z = 0 \\
x+5y-z-t = 0
\end{matrix}\right.
$$

I tried to find a general solution for $(*)$, didnt get exactly the vectors in $U$.

Is there is a more nice way to prove than very complicated calculations that i probably make mistakes in?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you agree that $U$ is contained in the solution space?

Comment: If $x$ is a solution for $Ax=0$ then $\alpha x$ is also a solution. So can you check if a linear combination of your solution with scalars from $\mathbb{Z}_7$ yield $U$?

Comment: How do you know that? @J.W.Tanner

Comment: I didnt understand what you, mean, take what i found and start checking for scalars and combinations? @lebesgue

Comment: Do you agree that $(1,-1,1,2)$ is in the solution space?

Answer (score 0):

The general solution is not very long to find,  from the RREF of the matrix of the linear system:
\begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix}
1&-1&1&2\\3&0&2&1
\end{pmatrix}\xrightarrow{R_2 \leftarrow 2 R_2}
&\begin{pmatrix}
1&-1&1&2\\-1&0&-3&2
\end{pmatrix}&\xrightarrow{R_2 \leftarrow-(R_1+ R_2)}
\begin{pmatrix}
1&-1&1&2\\ 0&1&2&3 
\end{pmatrix} \\[1ex]
{}\xrightarrow{R_1\leftarrow R_1+ R_2 }
&\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&3&-2\\ 0&1&2&3 
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
Therefore, the solutions are parameterised by
\begin{cases}
x=-3z+2t, \\y =-2z-3t
\end{cases}
For well-chosen values of $z$ and $t$, you obtain the given solutions.